# The Enter/Return key is not being read on a flutter webview using the webview_flutter package

Tags: flutter, webview, keyboard, plaid, webview-flutter

I'm using the [Plaid Link Web View](https://plaid.com/docs/link/webview/#create) for a flutter project i'm working on. I have installed the latest [Webview Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package. The web view has a text box to search for an institution (see Image 1.0).

Here's where i'm building the webview.

```
import 'package:ditch/settings.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class PlaidWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String linkToken;
  const PlaidWebView({
    super.key,
    required this.linkToken,
  });

  @override
  State<PlaidWebView> createState() => _PlaidWebViewState();
}

class _PlaidWebViewState extends State<PlaidWebView> {
  bool isAuthenticated = false;
  late String publicToken;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 50, 15, 50),
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl:
              'https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link.html?isWebview=true&token=${widget.linkToken}',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          navigationDelegate: (request) {
            if (request.url.contains('plaidlink://connected')) {
              isAuthenticated = true;
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            } else if (request.url.contains('plaidlink://exit')) {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Settings()),
              );
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            } else {
              print(request);
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Web View registers key inputs and updates the search query succesfully, this is the HTTP redirect when I type let's say "First Platypus Bank"]

```
flutter: NavigationRequest(url: plaidlink://event?error_code=&error_message=&error_type=&event_name=SEARCH_INSTITUTION&exit_status=&institution_id=&institution_name=&institution_search_query=**first%20platypus%20bank**&...)
```

**However, it does not register when I press the "Enter/Return" key on either a physical keyboard or on the I/O on the iOS simulator, or the keyboard on the phone when I run it from xcode directly on to my device. The results will not update unless I press the enter/return key.**

[Image 1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aacTZ.png)

I have visited the same web view on my browser and the results don't update automatically either but it does update when I press enter on the keyboard.

When I run this to my physical device using flutter this is the console output on the text input (may be unrelated)

2022-11-28 07:49:42.430862-0500 Runner[7222:1919659] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service

I've scraped the web for some time and I don't see other with the same issue, anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using the the [Plaid Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/plaid_flutter) plugin it does a really great job at natively integrating with both android and iOS and has a bunch of useful methods. Would highly advise you go this route.